# How do I get this nested for loop to work correctly?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a simulation where I watch a forest grow for 200 years. My forest has 25 trees in it. The goal is that each tree starts with a biomass of 1. Then each year that it stays alive it gains 600 biomass. If it dies it reverts back to 0 biomass. The problem I am running into now is that my trees all mimic each other, they are not growing individually. Any help is appreciated. I am running R version 3.2.1 on Windows 7.

```
simulation_years = 200
num_trees_side1 = 5
num_trees_side2 = 5
npp=600
mortality=0.02
forest = array(0,dim=c(simulation_years,num_trees_side1,num_trees_side2))
forest[1,,] = 1

for(i in 2:simulation_years){
    for(j in 1:num_trees_side1){  
     for(k in 1:num_trees_side2){
           forest[i,,] = forest[i] + npp
             rvar = runif(1,0,1)
        if(rvar < mortality){  
            forest[i,,] = 0} }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here `forest[i,,]=0`--you reset the whole "facet" to 0 whenever there's a mortality event. This should be `forest[i,j,k] = 0`.

Also, you don't need all of these `for` loops. Your problem is only truly recursive in one dimension--time--the other two dimensions can be handled at once. Here's how I'd do your problem:

```
num_trees = num_trees_side1 * num_trees_side2
for(i in 2:simulation_years){
  deaths=matrix(runif(num_trees)>mortality,
                ncol=num_trees_side2)
  forest[i,,] = deaths*(forest[i-1L,,]+
                          npp*(forest[i-1L,,]>0))
}
```

Let's work through an example with `simulation_years=2`.

```
set.seed(10239) #so we both get the same random numbers
```

After we run the above code, we can see which trees died by looking at `deaths`:

```
> deaths
      [,1] [,2] [,3]  [,4] [,5]
[1,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[3,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[4,]  TRUE TRUE TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[5,] FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Thus, the trees at `[5,1]` and `[5,4]` have died. Let's see the biomass by looking at `forest[2,,]`:

```
> forest[2,,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  601  601  601  601  601
[2,]  601  601  601  601  601
[3,]  601  601  601  601  601
[4,]  601  601  601  601  601
[5,]    0  601  601    0  601
```

As required, the two trees at `[5,1]` and `[5,4]` have died; the rest have grown by 600.

Comment: Thank you very much. The only other thing I may have not stated very clearly is that by year three if a tree has not died it should grow to 1201, then 1801, etc.

Comment: @pop_pop_pop yes, this is handled by my approach. once last thing--once a tree is dead, it's dead forever, correct? If so, see my edit, otherwise the original version is correct.